# How to private and hide some modules in last.fm profile

Tags: profile, last.fm

I have a profile on last.fm

- I want to hide it completely from any search results. Maybe show it
  only to people to whom I give direct link.
- I don't want visitors to see the any modules there like **Library** and **Top artist** and **top tracks**.

How would it be possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last.fm doesn't have the concept of "private" profiles, neither can you selectively hide modules, so this isn't possible.

*sidenote: I use last.fm for music discovery - hiding these is pointless and goes exactly against why you're using last.fm.*